# JavaScript Date NaN issue in IE?

Tags: javascript, date

I am facing problem while displaying date in IE, below is my JSON structure I am trying to display inStoreDate and firstMarkDownDate dates in the UI. It is working fine in the FF and Chrome but I am facing issues while coming to IE. In IE it is showing as NaN.

```
"data":[
  {
    "Id": "123",
    "inDate": [
        2012,
        12,
        17
    ]
  }
]
```

I am using the below date format function to format date before displaying.

```
formatDate: function(longDate) {
    var d = new Date(longDate);
    return ('0' + (d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '/'
            + ('0' + (d.getDate())).slice(-2) + '/'
            + d.getFullYear();
}

formatDate(data.inDate);
```

Comment: With which IE version you're having the problem?

Comment: @Teemu: all IE versions from IE7 to IE10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing an array to the `Date` constructor which is the cause of your problems. Arrays (as all objects) will be stringified and then parsed as-a-string when fed into the `Date` constructor - yet IE does not recognize the format `"2012,12,17"` as a valid date while Chrome does.

Instead, you should pass the three single values separately:

```
var date = new Date(longValue[0], longValue[1], longValue[2]);
```

Comment: Would it be simpler to just do `formatDateWithZero(data.inStoreDate.join('/'));`?

Comment: @Teemu: Good idea, that should work as well. It should not even suffer from timezone issues, but I don't like converting into a string and parsing back to numbers when they are already available.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MSDN Date specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), there is no normalized way to pass object as a parameter to the Date() function.

You will most probably need change the code to pass year, month and day to the function like so:

```
self.inStoreDate = formatDateWithZero(data.inStoreDate[0], data.inStoreDate[1], data.inStoreDate[2]);
```

... or update your functionality to take array but extract those values from it for the Date constructor:

```
formatDateWithZero: function(longValue) {
    var date = new Date(longValue[0], longValue[1], longValue[2]);
    return ('0' + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '/'
            + ('0' + (date.getDate())).slice(-2) + '/'
            + date.getFullYear();
}

self.inStoreDate = formatDateWithZero(data.inStoreDate);
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pt75S/2/

Comment: This one I tried but in some cases I may need to use the same formatDateWithZero function to format a longValue. So that is the reason I used new date to convert date inside the formatDateWithZero function.